# Jenkins: How to configure unstable builds of Cucumber steps?

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins

How to mark builds unstable with yellow balls, if certain amount of Cucumber tests are failed in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this Jenkins plugin : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fail+The+Build+Plugin

Comment: I am not sure how this plugin is related to my problem... Seems like this plugin allows to set build status manually, right?